# Fold Higher Order Function Using Lambda Expressions

Tags: python

I want to write a function that takes a function and uses a list to return the result.

```
#Sum_two
sum_two = lambda x, y: x + y

#Longer
def longer(s, t):
    # Take two strings
    # Return the longer
    # Return the first if equal in length
    if len(s) >= len(t):
        return s
    else:
        return t

def fold(f,x):
    return [item for item in x if f(item)]
```

Here's what it should do:

```
>>> fold(sum_two, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
15
>>> fold(longer, ['aa', 'bb', 'cccc', 'd'])
cccc
```

It only crashes.
I can't figure out how to fix it and need help. This is NOT a repeat of another question because it is fixing MY code, not how to do the problem. This is also not homework and is simply a way to better understand higher order functions.

Comment: Your "crash" should actually be an error message which is pretty clear.

Comment: @Nick I was referring to `fold`, not `sum_two`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica of course. wasn't paying attention.

Comment: _It only crashes_ Is that it? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, this won't work so simply. List comprehensions return lists and shouldn't be used for side effects, so they're not really the right tool here. You may just need to write a loop:

```
def fold(f,x):
    start, *rest = x
    for item in rest:
        start = f(start, item)
    return start

fold(sum_two, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
# 15
fold(longer, ['aa', 'bb', 'cccc', 'd'])
# 'cccc'
```

There's also [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) if you don't want to do it yourself.

Comment: This is probably the best way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a single value. As @MarkMeyer points out, you can iterate over the list, but you can also implement `fold` recursively:

```
def fold(f,x):
    if len(x) < 2:
        return x[0]
    elif len(x) == 2:
        return f(x[0], x[1])
    else:
        return f(x[0], fold(f, x[1:]))

fold(sum_two, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
# 15
fold(longer, ['aa', 'bb', 'cccc', 'd'])
# 'cccc'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use reduce:

```
from functools import reduce

sum_two = lambda x,y:x+y

longer = lambda x,y:x if len(x) >= len(y) else y

print(reduce(sum_two,[1,2,3,4,5]))
# 15
print(reduce(longer,['aa', 'bb', 'cccc', 'd']))
# cccc
```